# MEF / MVC parameterless controller constructor

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, mef

I am new to MEF and have some troubles using constructor injection.

I have this interface IModuleInfo

```
public interface IModuleInfo
{
  string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And have this abstract class:

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(IModuleInfo))]
public abstract class ModuleInfo : IModuleInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is a class from one of the modules:

```
public class InviteModuleInfo : ModuleInfo
{

}
```

And this is my controller:

```
[Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        IEnumerable<IModuleInfo> _modules;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public HomeController(IEnumerable<IModuleInfo> modules)
        {
            this._modules = modules;
        }
    }
```

But when running my application, this is the error I got:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'TestWeb.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller
>   has a parameterless public constructor.

This is my controller factory:

```
public class MefControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly CompositionContainer _container;

        private readonly DefaultControllerFactory _default;

        public MefControllerFactory(CompositionContainer container)
        {
            _default = new DefaultControllerFactory();
            _container = container;
        }

        public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            IController controller = null;
            bool noModule = false;

            var controllers = _container.GetExports<IController, IModuleAttribute>();

            if (controllers == null) noModule = true;
            else
            {
                controller = controllers.Where(a => a.Metadata.Controller.Equals(controllerName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    .Select(e => e.Value)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                if (controller == null) noModule = true;
            }

            if (noModule)
            {
                try
                {
                    controller = _default.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);


                }
                catch
                {
                    //throw new Exception("Controller " + controllerName + " not found!");
                    throw;


                }
            }
            else
            {

            }

            return controller;
        }
    }
```

Not sure what I missed.  :(

Comment: The error is saying your need an empty constructor in your HomeController.

Comment: yep, but was expecting that the constructor parameters will be resolved by MEF.. because it was looking for empty constructor, it means that it wasn't able to resolve the IEnumerable<IModuleInfo>...

Comment: i can use property injection with this factory by adding this line: _container.ComposeParts(controller). However I prefer to use constructor injection